# Android little endian MD5

Tags: java, android, endianness

I'm porting a Windows app to Android and I'm running into an issue with endianness. The app takes a series of text fields from the user and generates a password based on MD5. The problem is when I create the byte array to pass into the MD5 digest method, the bytes on the Android app are in big endian format. Thus, the MD5 output does not match between the two platforms.

I've tried using a ByteBuffer to convert to little endian and then copy that value back into the byte array using ByteBuffer.get(). Sadly, that doesn't work as it doesn't maintain the order setting.. This seems to be a known "gotcha" when dealing with ByteBuffers. If I compare the ByteBuffer.getLong() value and the equivalent in the windows version the values match  but I don't know how to get the array back out of the ByteBuffer in the correct order.

Edit: I've attached both the java and C# functions below.

Below is the java version that doesn't try to fix the order/endianness:

```
public static final long md5(final String input) {
    try {
        // Create MD5
        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        // Read in string as an array of bytes.
        byte[] originalBytes = input.getBytes("US-ASCII");
        byte[] encodedBytes = md5.digest(originalBytes);

        long output = 0;
        long multiplier = 1;

        // Create 64 bit integer from the MD5 hash of the input
        for (int i = 0; i < encodedBytes.length; i++) {
            output = output + encodedBytes[i] * multiplier;
            multiplier = multiplier * 255;
        }
        return output;

    } 
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the C# version

```
private Int64 MD5(string input)
{
  MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

  byte[] originalBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
  byte[] encodedBytes = md5.ComputeHash(originalBytes);
  Int64 output = 0;
  Int64 Multiplyer = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < encodedBytes.Length; i++)
  {
    output = output + encodedBytes[i] * Multiplyer;
    Multiplyer = Multiplyer * 255;
  }
  return output;
}
```

Comment: I think you're confused about the problem - there's no sense of "endianness" here - both the conversion from text to binary and the MD5 algorithm will produce simple byte arrays.

Comment: But doesn't it matter which order the bytes go into the digest method?

Comment: Yes, it does. The first byte that went into the windows version should be the first byte that goes into the android. But endian relates to order of bytes in a word, not in a byte stream.

Comment: Ok. In the windows version, the function is: byte[] originalBytes = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(input);. Is this just reading the bytes opposite of the android version?

Comment: What's confusing me is that  once I do the little endian order and compare the long values of both platforms the numbers match. If I don't do the little endian conversion, they do not match.

Comment: I'm confused. An MD5 digest is 16 bytes, whereas a `long` is only 8 bytes. So why does your `md5` method return a `long`? Wouldn't it make more sense to return a `String`, either Base-64-encoded (22 characters long) or hex-encoded (32 characters long)?

Comment: @quesauce: For a start, `ASCIIEncoding.Default` is an abomination - it's *not* ASCII, it's the platform default encoding. You should use `Encoding.UTF8` or something like that - and do the same in Java as well, of course.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I agree about the ASCIIEncoding.Default. I noticed it in the original source (I didn't write it). I've already sent a note to the author about it.

Comment: @ruakh: After we return the long we send it to a function that converts it to a base 62 number (a..z, A..Z, 0..9) and returns it as a string. I don't know why the author did it this way, but it's done and my company has decided to use it so now I have to emulate the functionality.

Comment: @quesauce: I think an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would help clarify what you're doing, and what's going wrong.

Comment: @ruakh: Done. The functions in both version are now included.

Comment: Wow, there is just so much wrong with that C# code. I feel your pain. ;-)

Comment: @ruakh: Agreed. That C# method shouldn't even be called `MD5` because it bears no resemblance to it.

Comment: If you hex-encode the `originalBytes` in each version, what do they each look like? Can you see which bytes in the C# version correspond to which bytes in the Java version?

Comment: @ruakh: That's what I'm working on right now.

Comment: @ruakh: The hexes of originalBytes in both versions match. Now I'm very confused.

Comment: @quesauce: And how about the hex-encodings of `encodedBytes`? Do they match?

Comment: @ruakh: Just did that test as well. I think this is where the problem is. They "sort of" match. Most of elements match exactly, but some of the android bytes are ffffffXX where the XX matches the output on the windows version. For example, the first byte of encodedBytes on the windows version is b2. The first byte on the android version is ffffffb2. This occurs in several other places throughout the array, but not everywhere.

Comment: @quesauce: O.K., I understand the issue. It'll take me a few minutes to write up an answer. In the meantime, go take a break. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this line of Java:

```
            output = output + encodedBytes[i] * multiplier;
```

is subtly different from this line of C# code:

```
    output = output + encodedBytes[i] * Multiplyer;
```

Specifically, the implicit conversion of `encodedBytes[i]` from `byte` to `long` (Java) or `Int64` (C#) is a bit different.

You see, in Java, a `byte` is a *signed* value between `-128` and `127`, whereas in C#, it's an *unsigned* value between `0` and `255`. So, for example, if `encodedBytes[i]` is `B2` (`1011 0010`), then Java interprets that as -78, while C# interprets that as 178.

To emulate the C# interpretation in Java, you can write something like this:

```
            output = output + ((encodedBytes[i] + 256) % 256) * multiplier;
```

(Fortunately, Java has the same handling for integer overflow as C#'s "unchecked" mode, which is apparently what you're using; *that* would have been much trickier to emulate, if you had to.)

Comment: You are a rock star. The android app works as expected now. I never even thought to compare the implementation differences of bytes! Thank you very much.

Comment: @quesauce: By the way, it didn't occur to me, either, until you said that `b2` was showing up as `ffffffb2` -- that is, that `1011 0010` was showing up as `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011 0010` -- clear evidence of [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension).

Answer (score 0):

The [MD5 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321) calls for 128-bit values, not 64-bit. So first of all, the signature `private Int64 MD5(string input)` makes no sense. You should not be converting these to integers and trying to compare them. Just pass around the `byte[]` references and compare those.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a choice. The original windows version has already been deployed and is in use. I just have to emulate what it does (even if it's incorrect).